# Remove LinkButton

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a `div` and inside this div, a `ContentPlaceHolder`, and inside the holder a `Linkbutton`.

I am trying to remove the link button dynamically but I am getting this error:

> Error: DOM Exception: NOT_FOUND_ERR (8).

Here is my code:

```
<div id="leftcol" style="z-index: 0">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton  CssClass="childLI" ID="tblRSManswers" runat="server" Text="RS Manswers" OnClick="ChildLink_Click" >
```

Javascript code:

```
var child = document.getElementById("tblRSManswers"));
alert(child);
var parent = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder2"));
alert(parent);
parent.removeChild(child);
```

P.S: The alerts are not NULL.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting `Unexpected token )`? (both your `getElementById` have an extra `)`).

Comment: when you display your page in browser inspect your linkbutton and see the id associated with it then do what you want to do.

Comment: You should post your rendered mark up. Also, I cannot see any closing tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`removeChild` expects an immediate parent. Your pasted HTML seems to be only excerpts of the most relevant code, so even though it looks like it in your code, I'm not sure this is the case in your real application?

Try

```
child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```

Comment: Then `child` is not a valid reference to the node you want to remove. You're probably specifying an incorrect ID, as per Muarli's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
document.getElementById("<%= tblRSManswers.ClientID %>").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("<%= tblRSManswers.ClientID %>"));
```

**Update:**

In ASP.Net ContentPlaceHolders are just a placeholder to render some HTML elements, but its not an actual DOM element. It will not be visible in page. So **finding content place holder with javascript always returns null, since it will not be rendered in DOM**

Comment: OP says the alerts are fine, though, so we can probably assume static ID.

Comment: the ClientID for a server control is unique for the page. so you can do this: var el = document.getElementById("<%= tblRSManswers.ClientID %>"); el.parentElement.removeChild(el);